# Symmetric encryption with a key size less than 128bit

Tags: openssl, aes, sensors, public-key-encryption

I'm implementing a cryptographic solution for Wireless and sensor network security. So in a one step of this implementation sensor nodes have a certificate of a CA. Sensors are supposed to generate a symmetric key and encrypt it with CA's public key and send it to the CA.

I use openssl for certificate and key generations. I though of using AES with 128bit key for the symmetric key. The problem for the moment is that I can't encrypt 128bit data as follows since it gives "Data is too large" error.

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey id_rsa.pub.pem -pubin -in key1.bin -out key1.bin.enc
```

So it looks like either I need to encrypt 128 bit key using another way or I can use a smaller key which in sensor network environment will not be a problem.

My question is "Is there any symmetric key encryption with smaller key or do I have a way to encrypt 128bit key using the certificate directly"

P.S

This is how I generate keys.

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -pubout > mykey.pub
openssl rand 128 > key1.bin
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [openssl rsautl documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsautl.html) page:

> rsautl because it uses the RSA algorithm directly can only be used to
>   sign or verify small pieces of data.

So don't expect to be able to encrypt large amounts of data with an RSA key.

HOWEVER, the RSA algorithm is frequently used to do exactly what you are proposing...encrypting an AES key, which is then used to encrypt larger files.

You should be able to encrypt (almost) up to your public key size.  So something seems wrong here.   For a public key size of 2048 bits (256 bytes), I can encrypt a 1960 bit (245 byte) file using the same openssl command in your question.  For a 1024 bit public key, I can encrypt 936 bits (117 bytes).

So let's check these items to see if the problem can be found:

First, how large is your RSA public key? (Be careful not to confuse bits and bytes.)  It should be 1024 bits or higher.

Next, how large is your AES key? (Again, make sure to check bits vs. bytes.)  It should be 128 bits according to your question.

If the sizes are correct for both keys, there should be no problem encrypting the AES key with the RSA key.

Comment: My public key is 1024 bits. That should be the problem.

Comment: You should be able to encrypt up to 117 bytes (936 bits) with a 1024 bit public key.  That is more than enough for a 128 bit AES key.  Try encrypting a text file containing about 16 characters to prove you can encrypt 128 bits.  Then increase the text file until the length is too long.  That should occur around 936 bits.

Comment: My fault I'm generating 128bytes using openssl rand. Thanks for helping out.